# Reading a custom XML String with asp.NET in VB

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

Okay I have a custom XML string that is provided so unable to modify structure it is a key value pair as seen here

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ContentStack ID='13' Type='11'>
    <ContentElement1 ID='11' Type='IMAGE'>
       <Key AttributeName='Name' AttributeValue='SOMENAME'></Key>
       <Key AttributeName='SRC' AttributeValue='SOMEFILE.jpg'></Key>
       <Key AttributeName='ALT' AttributeValue='SOMEALT'></Key>
       <Key AttributeName='Class' AttributeValue='SOMECLASS'></Key>
   </ContentElement1>
</ContentStack>
```

I want to be able to grab the `attribute value` and assign them to a variable so I end up with something like this.

```
Dim thsValueOne AS String = "SOMENAME"
Dim thsValueTwo AS String = "SOMEFILE.jpg"
Dim thsValueThree AS String = "SOMEALT"
Dim thsValueFour AS String = "SOMECLASS"
```

I have tried doing similar to this with no luck

```
Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(" MY XML STING IN HERE ")
thsValueOne = xDoc.Descendants("Key.AttributeValue").Skip(0).Take(1).ToString
```

I'm thinking I'm no where near close.

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation for the `Descendants` method, or are you just going from examples?

Comment: Yes basically I have a small string that is coming from a database cell that is set up as shown and I just want to be able to pull one of the Key item values and assign them to a variable

Comment: And, did you look at the documentation? Did you see any example of using "Key.AttributeValue"?

Comment: Didn't see any examples.. Most of examples I found in Documentation deals with quering XML that looks more like folowing then does a loop through. I only have one recordset in my String as shown in question above..

< Child1 >1< /Child1 >
< Child2 >2< /Child2 >
< Child3 >3< /Child3 >

Comment: I don't have time to work it out for you, but your syntax `Key.AttributeValue` is totally imaginary.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this but no luck with it either thsValueOne = xDoc.ContentStack.ContentElement1.Key.@AttributeValue

Comment: You really need to read the documentation. That is an XPATH syntax, and Descendants does not use XPATH.

Comment: Using this thsValueOne = xDoc.Root.Descendants.<Key>.@AttributeValue I end up with the correct first item but I'm not sure how to set it so it sets the second..

Comment: Okay I got it thanks for your help John thsValueTwo = xDoc.Root.Descendants.<Key>(1).@AttributeValue

Comment: You should answer your own question, showing how you got the results you were looking for. You can even accept your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok was able to get this figured out base on XML in question answer was simple

```
Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(thsXmlContent)
thsValueOne = xDoc.Root.Descendants.<Key>(0).@AttributeValue
thsValueTwo = xDoc.Root.Descendants.<Key>(1).@AttributeValue
thsValueThree = xDoc.Root.Descendants.<Key>(2).@AttributeValue
thsValueFour = xDoc.Root.Descendants.<Key>(3).@AttributeValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out any of the below workarounds, in order to understand the concept.

As you are using VB.NET you can use XML literals:

```
Private Sub test1()
    Dim xFrag = <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                <ContentStack ID='13' Type='11'>
                    <ContentElement1 ID='11' Type='IMAGE'>
                        <Key AttributeName='Name' AttributeValue='SOMENAME'></Key>
                        <Key AttributeName='SRC' AttributeValue='SOMEFILE.jpg'></Key>
                        <Key AttributeName='ALT' AttributeValue='SOMEALT'></Key>
                        <Key AttributeName='Class' AttributeValue='SOMECLASS'></Key>
                    </ContentElement1>
                </ContentStack>
    Dim query = xFrag...<Key>, pos& = 0
    For Each ele As XElement In query
        pos += 1
        MsgBox(String.Format("Test1:Key({0}):AttributeName='{1}' AttributeValue='{2}'", pos.ToString, ele.@AttributeName, ele.@AttributeValue))
    Next ele
End Sub
```

Or otherwise use the `Parse` method.

```
Private Sub test2()
    Dim xStr = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><ContentStack ID='13' Type='11'><ContentElement1 ID='11' Type='IMAGE'><Key AttributeName='Name' AttributeValue='SOMENAME'></Key><Key AttributeName='SRC' AttributeValue='SOMEFILE.jpg'></Key><Key AttributeName='ALT' AttributeValue='SOMEALT'></Key><Key AttributeName='Class' AttributeValue='SOMECLASS'></Key></ContentElement1></ContentStack>"
    Dim xFrag = XDocument.Parse(xStr)
    Dim query = xFrag...<Key>, pos& = 0
    For Each ele As XElement In query
        pos += 1
        MsgBox(String.Format("Test2:Key({0}):AttributeName='{1}' AttributeValue='{2}'", pos.ToString, ele.@AttributeName, ele.@AttributeValue))
    Next ele
End Sub
```

Hope this helps...